# Where to put abstractions in SOLID programming?

Tags: design-patterns, interface, dependency-injection, abstraction, solid-principles

I develop a game engine in XNA. This engine has some modules (subprojects), such as Renderer, StateManagement, etc.

Refering to Dependency Inversion Principle: "High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions." My question is: Where should I put those abstractions in practice? Should I create some projects with groups of corresponding abstractions, or create one project with all the abstractions of my engine? The first solution will mess up my project structure, the second one will demand creation of project with tons of abstract classes with all other projects depending on it. Maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although sometimes people do put their interfaces in separate projects, often the interfaces are simply placed side-by-side their implementations. One could argue that using separate projects ensures that one codes to those interfaces, but I find it is better to rely on discipline and dependency discovery tools to ensure you code to interfaces.

Comment: It should be noted that these kinds of interfaces (especially those placed side by side with their implementations) are not usually abstractions at all, they are merely a layer of indirection to accommodate IoC. For example, `IFooRepository` is no more abstract than `FooRepository`.

Comment: Often, yes. But especially when building libraries or frameworks, there will often be sensible basic implementations with the explicit intent to add more specific ones in particular projects. In that case, those abstractions may well become an important part of the library itself.

Comment: Although I do place interfaces close to the implementations sometimes, you have you watch out for violations of the [Reused Abstraction Principle](http://codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934).

Comment: There are always at least two implementations of an interface; one for test(s).

Comment: @Steven Interesting article there. What is your approach to unit testing and mocks then? We have many classes that are the single implementations of an interface in our project, due to the ability to mock said dependencies later on when testing consumer classes. Most mocking frameworks can only mock interfaces or virtual methods/abstract classes. I find it much worse to remove the `sealed` from my classes and mark all methods virtual rather than having an interface backing them for testing. Based on that article, these interfaces of ours are bad smells, but what is the correct approach then?

Comment: @julealgon: I believe that a mock or fake implementation of an interface is considered to be a second implementation and in that case you are adhering to the Reused Abstraction Principle. But, still if you have many one-to-one mappings (leaving fake versions aside), your design might be suboptimal. Using generic interfaces for instance can help a lot (see for instance [here](https://bit.ly/11yJdS5) and [here](https://bit.ly/19vZRuv)).